# Why does UPDATE not set a later end time?

Tags: postgresql, node-pg-pool

### node-pg

```js
await db.query(
`DO $$ 
 DECLARE 
     pbid INT;
 BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO public.bp(process_id) SELECT ${ID} RETURNING id INTO pbid;
     COMMIT;
     REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.vm WITH DATA;
     UPDATE public.bp SET under_process = FALSE, ended_at = now() WHERE id = pbid;
 END;$$;`
);
```

This script executes fine but ended_at is **always** the same time as start time.
The refresh takes around 2 min.

P.S.: I have a trigger ***currently disabled*** that does `new.ended_at := now();`

At least tell me why this is happening.

Comment: And how is "start time" set? Postgres version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), NOW() returns the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction.

While clock_timestamp() returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command

Use clock_timestamp() to solve your issue.

Comment: too bad i can't give you more than 1 hhhh

Comment: @RamiJamleh: Sure you can. Reward a bounty.